# Работа с Com портом, последовательно отправляя запросы и принимая ответы

Tags: c#, com-port, rs232

Несколько дней бъюсь с такой проблемой:

Есть устройство, которое обменивается данными с ПК по RS232 на скорости 115200 бод. Устройство многоканальное.

В процессе работы опрашивается каждый канал, и на пк должны приходить сообщения со значениями некоторых величин на канале.
Алгоритм работы такой:

1. Отправить запрос на чтение данных с канала 1

2. Принять сообщение с данными канала 1

3. Отправить запрос на чтение данных с канала 2

4. Принять сообщение с данными канала 2

и т.д.

Причём всё должно отправляться и читаться без задержек, по крайней мере принудительных (важно время выполнения вышеперечисленных действий).

Теперь к проблеме:

После отправления запроса, данные с порта сразу же после этого могут не прочитаться, следом отправляется второй запрос - читаются данные для первого запроса и так далее... либо метод может вернуть массив с нулями

Привожу огрызок кода:

```
...
Port port = new Port();
byte[] dataMessage1 = port.GetIpchCurrentValues(chanel1);
byte[] dataMessage2 = port.GetIpchCurrentValues(chanel2);
byte[] dataMessage3 = port.GetIpchCurrentValues(chanel3);
...

class Port
{
    ...
    public byte[] GetIpchCurrentValues(int chanel)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[14];

        port.Write(Commands.ReadValues(chanel), 0, 14);

        port.Read(buffer, 0, 14);

        return ipchMessageInput;
    }
}
```

Пробовал через событие - там дело обстоит ещё хуже, приходит лишь бы что..
Может кто в курсе, в чём может быть проблема?

Comment: И ещё, шагая по коду, заметил, что данные в буфер могут сохраняться со сдвигом влево на 1 байт

Comment: Устройство передает заголовок начала передачи данных?

Comment: @ГеннадийП, в документации протокола обмена на устройство, что имеется у меня, к сожалению, никакой информации по этому поводу нет

Answer (score 0):

Работать всё-таки надо через событие, складывая принятые данные в буфер и проверяя целостность посылки (протокол это позволяет?).

Учтите, что все 14 байт могут быть не приняты за раз, вот почему я написал "складывая в буфер"

В простейшем случае нужно проверять результат `port.Read(buffer, 0, 14);` - функция ведь возвращает количество прочитанных байт и повторять чтение в цикле `while`

Comment: да, протокол это позволяет.
Но есть такой вопрос: Мне придётся останавливать основной поток, чтобы отработал фоновый по приёму данных?

Comment: заметил ещё такой момент, если чтение портов выполняется по разовому нажатию на кнопку - всё гуд. т.е. нажал на одну кнопку - получил данные с одного канала, нажал на другую - с другого. Всё читается сразу и без проблем. Как такое может быть?

Comment: По нажатию на кнопку есть много времени для приёма. Кроме того, может быть что-то не то с таймаутами, да и другие подробности реализации нам неизвестны. Добавил в ответ предложение чтения в цикле